# In need of an Regular expression. For stripping outlook HYPERLINK "urlname"

Tags: c#, regex, url, hyperlink, outlook

I've run into a little problem. Im making an Outlook Add-in, where i can archive an email.

When an email contains html/xhtml etc it converts hyperlinks into HYPERLINK "url".
Example:

```
HYPERLINK "Company URL" 1 x Mexicano
HYPERLINK "Company URL" € 1,75
HYPERLINK "Company URL" 1 x Patat
HYPERLINK "Company URL" € 1,25
```

each line should be an clickable URL, but for some reason outlook doesnt give plain text but this instead...

So i want to strip my string from: HYPERLINK "any characters here"

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex ("HYPERLINK \"(.*?)\"");
```

This will match `Company URL` in `HYPERLINK "Company URL" 1 x Mexicano`, if that's what you were looking for.